# next.js, styled-components, react-helmet. How to use all together

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, next.js, react-helmet

I'm facing an issue that I can't use the `react-helmet` and the `styled-component` together with `next.js`.

Inside the examples provided by next.js, they are using each package in different repos. Can anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Please include your code in the post. Otherwise, it's very difficult for people to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `react-helmet`, you can use an existing nextJS lib [next/head](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#user-content-populating-head).

For `styled-component`, I'm not sure about your case but there is an example of nextJS using `styled-component` [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-styled-components).

Comment: You cannot modify `<html>` with that.

Comment: what do u want to achieve? both react-helmet and styled-component doesn't have any purpose to modify <html> tag.

Comment: You probably sometimes would like set dynamically lang attribute for <html> tag... and that is not possible with next/head.
But react-helmet can be handy for that,

Comment: you can modify your lang in <html> tag by using `_document.js` file. Read more here https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document, it is a wrapper for all of your pages. No need to have react-helmet on your nextjs app.

Comment: I am speaking about cases when app is using for example apollo server/client, so any query executed will be executed mostly in deeper components, like metadata fetching for current page, therefor you cannot make it work on _document.